# Redirect from facebook causing error because of added address ending

Tags: php

I have created in my website simple file routing.php and created switch to redirect to file depends from url. My routing.php looks like:

```
<?php
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// $request = substr($request, 0, strpos($request, "?"));
switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
        require_once 'index.php';
        break;
    case '/o-inwestycji' :
        require_once 'about.php';
        break;
    case '/galeria' :
        require_once 'gallery.php';
        break;
    case '/lokalizacja' :
        require_once 'localisation.php';
        break;
    case '/kontakt' :
        require_once 'contact.php';
        break;
    case '/login' :
    require_once 'login.php';
    break;
}
?>
```

My problem is when I will send a link to website in facebook. When user will click link facebook add to link additional parameter in url and my urls looks like:

```
www.example.com/login?fbclid=IwAR3xVjfqiDVOiqc9p3b2wtl5gL_OBvlLN3aWTWgWMiHGEgIx8TagsGxHkqI
```

That mechanism cause error in my website and user is redirected to blank page. I tried to delete all characters after `?` but that's not working always well. Could you help me to solve that problem? Thank you!

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to extract only the path component from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with:

```
$request = substr($request, 0, strpos($request, "?"));
```

is that if there is no `?` present `strpos` evaluates to false and comes out as you wanted the string to be `0` length. e.g. the same as:

```
echo substr('test', 0, false);
```

You can change that so you check if there is a `?` before using:

```
$request = strpos($request, "?") !== FALSE ? substr($request, 0, strpos($request, "?")) : $request;
```

Additionally, you should add a `default` case to your `switch` so when a match doesn't occur the user ends up in an expected location.

You could probably get rid of:

```
case '/' :
        require_once 'index.php';
break;
case '/login' :
    require_once 'login.php';
break;
```

and use:

```
default:
     require_once 'login.php';
```

after all the other cases. You can read more about this here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php.

Comment: Yeah, that was mistake I did in file. Thank you so much :)